How to manipulate/join multiple strings containing UTF-8 characters
My code needs to be compatible with both Python 2.x and 3.x versions. I am getting both string as input to my function, and I need to do some manipulation on those:
if len(str1) > 10:
    str1 = str1[:10] + '...'
if six.PY3:
    return ' : '.join((str1, str2))

For Python 2.x, the above join is giving error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

What is the cleaner way of handling such cases for all versions of 2.x and 3.x?
As both the string are input to my code, I need to ensure that even if either of these strings contain UTF-8 characters, they should be joined properly.
Declaration : I am very new to Python.

@mkrieger1 I did not get the question. Not sure if there is a separate data type for this in Python, but from a strongly typed language perspective, those are strings, which may or may not contain UTF-8 chars.

@deceze I am very new to Python, like a couple of days. Can you please elaborate more on this? What do you mean by handle them as strings?

There's no such thing as UTF-8 chars. This entire page is UTF8. UTF8 is an encoding, a way to convert characters to bytes. The encoding applies to an entire string or file, not just parts of it. All strings in Python 3 are Unicode. In Python 2, you'll have to use the unicode type instead of str

As for the error itself, you'd get it if you tried to read any file with the wrong encoding. ascii is the 7-bit US-ASCII encoding. 0xC2 is the byte value of the letter Â in Latin1, the encoding used in the Western Europe and the Americas. In UTF8, characters above the US-ASCII range are encoded using 2 or more bytes, eg £ is encoded as 0xC2 0xA3.

@PanagiotisKanavos I am not reading from any file. One of the strings is coming from an API response. Another is a user input to this function.

JSON uses UTF8 so I suspect the API response is UTF8 and the user input isn't. You'll have to convert both strings to the unicode type. How do you read the user input? Post your code in the question itself

Do you really need this to work in Python 2? P2 has been dead for years, deprecated for over a decade. Writing any new code in Python 2 now is madness. Especially when it deals with strings, since that was one of the major changes between Python 2 and 3 and needs a really good understanding of both languages to handle properly. Which as a newbie seems a big task to tackle.

@deceze Totally agreed. Had this been a personal project, I would not use Py2.x. But there are still some legacy services in production, running heavily on Py2.x

Note: there are many more subtilities. I often add a ZWNJ before the dots, else the dots may be joined to the previous character, but it is also a lazy solution (you may break characters or emoji, which are multi-character(multi-codepoint) things.

In Python 3, you're usually, hopefully, pretty much exclusively dealing with str. That's the data type for strings. It expresses characters. Those characters aren't in any particular encoding; when manipulating them, you do not need to understand encodings. str1[:10] means "the first 10 characters", whether they are "abcdefghij" or "文字化けは楽しいんだ".
When encoded to actual bytes, the type is bytes. You do not want to be dealing with bytes when manipulating text.
In Python 2, because reasons, what is str in Python 3 was unicode in Python 2. What is bytes in Python 3 was str in Python 2.
String literals '' in Python 3 are strs, in Python 2 they're str (expressing bytes). The right string literal to express unicode in Python 2 is u''. u'' still works in Python 3 and maps to Python 3 str; so they express character based types in both languages.



Python 3
Python 2
expresses




str, literal: '', u''
unicode, literal: u''
characters


bytes, literal: b''
str, literal: '', b''
bytes



Concatenating str to bytes in Python 3 explicitly fails with a TypeError, but in Python 2 may or may not have funky side effects and implicit encoding conversions. You do not want to mix unicode and str in Python 2. Mostly you want to make sure everything is unicode.
So what you want to have it work in both languages is:
if len(str1) > 10:
    str1 = str1[:10] + u'...'
return u' : '.join((str1, str2))

And then you want to make sure str1 and str2 are str in Py3 and unicode in Py2. How to do that exactly depends on where they're coming from.

Thanks! This solution looks better than the conditional handling of version check.
This statement helped clear things for me - How to do that exactly depends on where they're coming from.

Yes, you should make sure that your app is handling inputs in some sane way that leaves you with character types in both languages. If not, and you're getting str in both languages (fundamentally different types), then you're in a world of hurt.
